# Magento 2.4 PWA : How to setup with LEMP stack using Docker

Tags: magento2, nginx, pwa, docker, magento2.4

If someone setup Magento 2.4 PWA using Docker with LEMP stack... Please give me supports.

Comment: Thank you @Chikku for your comment... I need LEMP stack, not LAMP.

Comment: you can use this https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/dockerizing-lemp-stack-with-docker-compose-on-ubuntu/